# Set DataGrid column width to Star in style

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, datagrid

how I can set in XAML width of DataGrid header to `*`?
This code doesn't work:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CbClmn" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="TxtClmn" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="*" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CbClmn}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource TxtClmn}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CbClmn}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Style `TxtClmn` generates exception `'*' string cannot be converted to Length`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the object browser:

```
//DataGridColumn
public System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength Width { set; get; }

//DataGridColumnHeader
public double Width { set; get; }
```

That's why u can't do that. It's of double type.

Comment: But why I can set Width in element attribute to star and it will work?
Example: <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Selected" Width="*" />

Comment: @Boo In this case you set the Width to Column (**DataGridColumn** type), but not to it's header (**DataGridColumnHeader** type).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, @Artion, but my problem still not resolved — I can't set width for columns. 
I try use <Style TargetType="DataGridColumn"> and set Width to star there, but it doesn't get any effect.

Comment: @Boo **DataGridColumn** doesn't derive from **FrameworkElement**, that's why you can't apply a **style**. Please read about column styling here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630292/why-i-cant-style-the-datagridtextcolumn.