# DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle for all DataGrids

Tags: wpf, validation

While MSDN seems to be confusing by saying ["you cannot use the Validation.ErrorTemplate attached property like you would with simple controls"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622975(v=vs.100).aspx), I found it is possible in every of my window xaml to set validation error template like below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    ...
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" 
                    Value="{StaticResource MyValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

What I want now is to set the error template for all datagrids in a shared themes resource dictionary. But I can't do the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" 
            Value="{StaticResource MyValidationErrorTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

because `DataGridTextColumn` isn't inherited from `FrameworkElement`; therefore cannot have style property (see [Why can't I style a DataGridTextColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630292/why-i-cant-style-the-datagridtextcolumn)).

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: did you ever figure this one out? We're in the process of making a datagrid style for our application, and would like to avoid having to inline specify EditingElementStyle on every column

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the answer to the same question. You can make the assignment slightly less verbose with something like the following style.

```
<Style x:Key="TextColumnErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ErrorTemplateStyle}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="2*"  Header="IP Address" 
    Binding="{Binding IpDestination,    
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextColumnErrorStyle}"/>
```

Ugh.