# WPF DataGrid columns don't use my default element styles

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Is there any way at all I can get a DataGrid to use my default element styles in DataGridTextColumn, DataGridComboBoxColumn, DataGridCheckBoxColumn and DataGridHyperlinkColumn?

As far as I can tell this property is not available to be set in the ResourceDictionary and the only way to override the styles is to set the ElementStyle and EditingElementStyle explicitly per column at the time the DataGrid is generated.

I really want this code to automatically use my styles for the elements inside the columns...

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" />
```

This code makes it work, but it's a lot of extra that has to be added for every DataGrid...

```
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"
                            Binding="{Binding FirstName}"
                            EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name"
                            Binding="{Binding LastName}"
                            EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Website"
                                 Binding="{Binding Website}"
                                 EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Newsletter"
                                Binding="{Binding Newsletter}">
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                         Value="Center" />
              </Style>
           </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
           <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}"
                     BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
                 <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                         Value="Center" />
              </Style>
           </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Image"
                            Binding="{Binding Image}"
                            EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define a default style for DataGridTextColumn. Except you can't, see this question: [Why can't I style a DataGridTextColumn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630292/why-i-cant-style-the-datagridtextcolumn).

To clarify, what I mean is that what I *wish* you could do is this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridTextColumn}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter PropertyName="EditingElementStyle" Value="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

However, that won't work for the reasons outlined in the best answer to that other question. I think if you really need this what you would want to do is take an approach something like the answer to that other question. Specifically, you would want to define an attached property for DataGrids that would use procedural code to "magically" iterate and apply your desired styles as rows were added. Then you would only need to add this one attached property to each of your DataGrid instances, instead of all that verbose styling.

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to do this all from a resource dictionary without the need for any extra code behind or xaml mark up. I'm clinging onto a hope that I've missed some blindingly obvious solution.