# How to add row to Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a problem adding a poem in a way I added to red in the picture.
How do I change my code to get that effect?

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="tableDateFromTo">
    <DatePicker x:Name="dateFrom" SelectedDateFormat="Short" SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_DataFrom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" FontSize="14" Width="100"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="dateTo"   SelectedDateFormat="Short" SelectedDateChanged="DatePiker_DataTo"    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="311,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="28" FontSize="14" Width="100"/>
    <Label x:Name="label"       Content="Wybierz zakres dat: Od" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,56,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16"/>
    <Label x:Name="labelDateTo" Content="Do"                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="280,56,0,482" FontSize="16"/>
    <Button x:Name="checkDateFromTo" Content="Wybierz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="416,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="16" Height="28" Width="75" Click="CheckDateFromTo_Click"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataOfCleanRooms" 
              CanUserSortColumns="False" Margin="0,157,-0.4,0.4"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding ID}"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Piętra 1-2" Binding="{Binding ServiceDays1to2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serwis duży"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serwis mały"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Piętra 3-5" Binding="{Binding ServiceDays3to5}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serwis duży"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Serwis mały"></DataGridTextColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Piętra 6-8" Binding="{Binding ServiceDays6to8}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please indent your XML, every single line of your XML, with at least four spaces on the left margin. Any line of XML that is not indented will vanish and will not be seen.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630292/why-cant-i-style-a-datagridtextcolumn which should help you get started